# ImportError: No module named xxxx after adding app to INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm creating a blog in Django, but I've had some troubles trying to import thrid party modules, for instance, I just tried to import the [django_markdown module](https://github.com/klen/django_markdown) to add a MarkDown field in my post model  for the post body, I followed the instructions in the reddit package page, but when I try to run my django server it returns:

```
...
ImportError: No module named 'django_markdownraulchirinos'
```

Due to "raulchirinos" is my django app, I suppouse it's a problem with my project structure or with my config paths.

Here's my models.py file:

```
from django.db import models
from django_markdown.models import MarkdownField
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body = MarkdownField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Raúl Chirinos')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: u can use `pip install django-markdown`

Comment: You are missing the comma after `'django_markdown'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting.